# SQL query to Google's JSON format

Tags: php, sql, json, google-visualization

I have posted a code snippet a few days ago about [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337511/mutiple-records-to-google-charts). I try to examine this problem from another side.

**So**, I have a query and I would like to fill in a json file from its output. It contains more records, not only one. The problem is, that all the code, that I have found / I have wrote paste only the first record into the file with the cols. I think there is no existing tutorial about this problem.

**UPDATE:** Sample output:

```
Array (
[cols] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [label] => Name
                [pattern] => 
                [type] => string
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [label] => Start
                [pattern] => 
                [type] => date
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [label] => End
                [pattern] => 
                [type] => date
            )

    )

[rows] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [c] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => X
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => Date(2014,08,18,21,00,00)
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => Date(2014,08,18,23,00,00)
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [c] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => Y
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => Date(2014,08,18,21,00,00)
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => Date(2014,08,18,22,00,00)
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [c] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => Z
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => Date(2014,08,18,23,00,00)
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => Date(2014,08,18,23,30,00)
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Comment: There is a lot about this question that may seem obvious to you but unfortunately is completely missing form the body of your question. If you could add the code you have written, and some sample data that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I have updated my question with a sample output.

Comment: I was really expecting you to add "the code" as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
It was a character encoding problem, that can be detected with json_last_error() method:

```
                switch (json_last_error()) {
                case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
                    echo ' - No errors';
                break;
                case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
                    echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
                break;
                case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
                    echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
                break;
                case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
                    echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
                break;
                case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
                    echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
                break;
                case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
                    echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
                break;
                default:
                    echo ' - Unknown error';
                break;
                }
```