# Google Timeline - b[bc] is not a function

Tags: google-visualization

I have a Google Timeline based graph. It was worked properly, perfectly earlier. I have perceived yesterday, that it gives only a blank page with this message: `b[bc] is not a function`.

I use a generated (from SQL query) JSON file as source, I also checked this and error free, seems valid. I have not modified anything on this. What is your oppinion, what causes this problem?

[image: b[bc] is not a function]

Comment: How on earth should anyone be able to answer? No code, no example reproducing the problem, no link to the website where the problem occurs ...? Please provide more info :)

Comment: JSON file looks like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358760/sql-query-to-googles-json-format. I would like only interpret the error code, beacuse it was working for weeks. I have not made any modification.

Comment: You were probably referencing the dataTable or the Chart properties with something other than the public methods, need to view code though